# Compiling program in C

Tags: c, makefile, emacs, compilation

this is my first question here. I have been compiling a Debian package in C (**emacs**). It is also my first compilation, so I don't understand much about it (until now).

I have the following structure:

- A folder with all the files needed for the compilation (the result of extracting the tar.gz source code package) in `/home/user/emacs`.
- A folder in which I've installed the program by using `make install` in `/opt/emacs` (because I specified that path while doing the `./configure`, in the `--prefix` argument).

As you all know, Linux uses a `$PATH` variable where all the paths that Linux should use to search for binaries are specified. By default, `/opt/emacs/bin` is obviusly not contemplated in that variable, and it is not an option for me to include it. The possible solution that I've heard about is to create a softlink in `/usr/local/bin` folder, which aims to that `/opt/emacs/bin/*` files.

Here comes my question. That `/opt/emacs` also has a `lib/` subdirectory. Would it be needed to also create a softlink for those libraries in `/usr/local/lib` for emacs to correctly work, or with the binary softlink is enough?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Perhaps the library is for use in another C program.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is not standard in PATH either.

Comment: @stark `/usr/local/bin` is the 1st entry in my $PATH variable.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I think you didn't understand the question. Is there any need to also link the `/opt/emacs/lib/*` files to `/usr/local/lib/` or by linking the binaries should be enough for them to work?

Comment: You can try it and see if it works. Or you can use `ldd` on each binary and see what libraries it would pull in at runtime. Can you list the libraries in `/opt/emacs/lib`? That would clarify the issue enormously. Finally, why not omit the prefix and build everything in `/usr/local`? And BTW, the question is probably more appropriate for the Unix & Linux SE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if emacs only needs the binary symlink or the library directory as well. Try running it. If it needed the libraries and cannot find them, it will fall over rather quickly.

Let's assume that the libraries are needed. You have several options for installing them (choose at most one):

- copy or link libraries to a library directory that's known to the system (e.g. /usr/local/lib), run `ldconfig` afterwards. On second thoughts, don't do this one, it's the worst option.
- edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` to add the emacs library directory there, run `ldconfig`
- launch emacs through e.g. a shellscript that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to its lib directory and then runs it

For more in-depth details see https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: actually looking at an emacs install the contents of the library directory don't look very exciting and you will probably not notice if they don't work, so these instructions may be unnecessary

Comment: So how can I make sure that it is perfectly working?

Comment: One of the files in the lib directory appears to be the [hex editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html). Try it out. If that works, your emacs should be fully working...

Comment: I've just checked my lib/ folder after installing with `make install` and there are no libraries. "/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service" this is the only file in that path. After looking at the other directories, I found libexec/, but it has binaries, not libraries. Maybe this is because when linking, it make an static link, not dinamic.